# having puppeteer browser as global instance open at all time vs using new browser instance for each request

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i have some web addresses in my db , i need to check these addresses for something and updated them in the db accordingly ... i need to do this over and over

here is simplified version of my code , i have two functions

1 - `init` -> reads an address row from db , pass the address to second function to check and  update the result in db for that address

2 - `check_address` -> checking that address in the browser and returning the result

here is simplified version of my code

```
async function init()
{
    try
    {
        let address = 'select * from addressess order by updated_at asc limit 1';
        let result = await check_address(address);
        await address.update({result : result });

    }
    catch(e){}

    setTimeout( ()=> init() , 5000 );
}


async function check_address( address )
{
    var browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    let result = await 'open a tab  , go to the address and cehck';
    // close the browser
    return result ;
}

init();
```

i feel like opening and closing browser for each address is very time/resource consuming , so i thought maybe i could have a global browser open at all time and just open and close tabs in the browser or maybe even use the same tab ... something like

```
let globalBrowser = false ;
async function check_address( address )
{
    if(!globalBrowser)
    {
        globalBrowser = await puppeteer.launch();
        globalBrowser._process.once('close', () => {
            globalBrowser = false;
        });
    }

    let result = await 'open a tab  , go to the address and cehck';
    return result ;
}
```

but im not sure if having a browser open at all time is ok , or this flow generally is a good idea

i have very limited experience with puppeteer ,  i would love some input from someone with more experience and knowledge of long running puppeteer app

Comment: Yes, I would keep the same `puppeteer` instance going.  You can create new pages in the same instance with `const page = await browser.newPage();` or you can go to a new url on an existing page with  `await page.goto('https://example.com');`.  You will obviously not want to just abandon pages without closing them or reusing them as that will accumulate more and more memory usage.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanx , what do you think about running puppeteer function inside it's parent function try/catch ... instead of having a separate try/catch in puppeteer function ... is it even possible to have second try/catch inside the first one (different functions ) ? i was thinking i might end up with lots of open tabs in the browser in case of navigation errors or something like that

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking about `try/catch`.  You put a `try/catch` at any level where you want or need to handle the error.  You can have multiple levels of `try/catch` in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, opening and closing the browser is performanced heavy. If your script is running on a server you could open the browser initially and do a cron job (@package [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)) every X hours on the `check_adress` function.

Instead of closing the browser you could simply close the current page page via:

```
await page.close();
```